# Apply Regex Pattern on key from nested list of objects of custom dictionaries

Tags: python, regex, list, class, filter

I have a nested list of objects called "words". It consists of objects of a class that has data like conf(float), end(float), start(float), word(string) I want to apply regex pattern "\b(\w+)\b(?=.*?\b\1\b)" on "word" and remove objects that match the pattern

```
class Word:
    ''' A class representing a word from the JSON format for vosk speech recognition API '''

    def __init__(self, dict):
        '''
        Parameters:
          dict (dict) dictionary from JSON, containing:
            conf (float): degree of confidence, from 0 to 1
            end (float): end time of the pronouncing the word, in seconds
            start (float): start time of the pronouncing the word, in seconds
            word (str): recognized word
        '''

        self.conf = dict["conf"]
        self.end = dict["end"]
        self.start = dict["start"]
        self.word = dict["word"]

    def to_string(self):
        ''' Returns a string describing this instance '''
        return "{:20} from {:.2f} sec to {:.2f} sec, confidence is {:.2f}%".format(
            self.word, self.start, self.end, self.conf*100)


    def compare(self, other):
        if self.word == other.word:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

here is the collection of objects

[image]

each object contain data like this

```
{'conf': 0.0, 'end': 0.00, 'start': 0.00, 'word': 'hello'} 

{'conf': 0.0, 'end': 1.00, 'start': 0.00, 'word': 'hello'} 

{'conf': 0.0, 'end': 2.00, 'start': 0.00, 'word': 'to'}
```

I tried to apply regex pattern this way but couldn't get it working

```
pattern = re.compile("\b(\w+)\b(?=.*?\b\1\b)")
for w in words:
    lst = [x for x in w.word if not re.match(pattern, x)]
print(lst)
```

Regex I tested Online
[image]

can some good soul guide me on how to apply regex pattern on "word" and remove objects that matches the pattern Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the error you're facing?

Comment: its producing unexpected output like this ['n', 'o', 't']

Comment: i'm still unclear about the actual input format.

Comment: input is a list "words" consist of objects each object consists of dictionaries each dictionary consist of data like conf(float), end(float), start(float), word(string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    if not re.match(pattern, words[i].word):
        lst.append(i)
print(lst)
# lst will have index of objs that satisfy the above condition
```

You can then use the indices to remove the objects from your list of objects.

EDIT: according to your comments, I've updated the answer:

```
distinct_words = {}
lst = []
for i in range(len(words)):
    if isinstance(distinct_words.get(words[i].word), int):
        lst.append(i)
    else:
        distinct_words[words[i].word] = i
print(lst)
```

Add the current word to distinct word dict with its index, if the word is found again then append it to lst else update the new word with the dict.

At the end lst will contain indices of all the repeated words. So use the indices in lst to remove the objects from the list.

Comment: Its not matching the regex properly it prints all the indices [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118]

Comment: problem is that when we try to apply regex to a single word it does not match but I tested this regex on whole paragraph online and that matches the required word

Comment: @KedNIMBALKAR Your pattern wont give a match if the value of attribute 'word' of the object is just a single word. That is why it returned all the indices. The regex will produce a match only if there are more than one word in the value of attribute 'word' hence it works in a paragraph.

Comment: my list has only 1 word in each object. any idea on how can I remove those by regex expression matching?

Comment: @KedNIMBALKAR I suggest that you change your regex to match your requirement. What exactly are you trying to match? What kind of words do you want removed?

Comment: I dont want to remove any specific words. I remove mainly repeating words or phrases

Comment: If you want to remove repeating words, where each word is a value of attribute of objects, then I suggest that you use python code. Since it cant be done with regex.

Comment: I found this cool package https://github.com/ermanh/trieregex
do you think this can do the job?

Comment: @KedNIMBALKAR You can do this without using any extra library. I've updated the answer. Check if the code works for you.

Comment: a regex query has more logic and I am looking forward to use that instead of this simple duplicate or distinct logic